# If $x_k :=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_{i,k}e_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with at the least a divergent coefficient, does that imply $||x_k||$ diverge?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $B=\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be a real base of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\{\alpha_{i,k}\}_k$ be real sequences, $i=1,...n$. Define $x_k :=\sum_{i=1}^n  \alpha_{i,k}e_k $

Suppose that for some $i_0 \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ we have that $|\alpha_{i_0,k}|\to \infty$, is it always true that $||x_k|| \to \infty$?

I'm sure it works with the canonical base,and it should be easy to adapt this for any orthogonal base. Furthermore, with a generic base and $k=2$, seems to work.

Comment: [All norms on finite dimensional vector spaces are equivalent](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=norm+equivalent+finite+dimensional+space) (this requires some work). So define a new norm by $\Vert\sum\alpha_k e_k\Vert'=\sum_k|\alpha_k|$. Since this is equivalent to the euclidian norm, there is $C>0$ such that $\Vert\cdot\Vert'\leq C\Vert\cdot\Vert$. The same proof as the one for the canonical base will work.

Comment: That's a very clean proof, thanks!